# Growth of partial sums of a divergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to find how the product $\prod_{n=0}^Me_n$ grows with $M$, when $$e_n=1+\frac{a_1}{t+n}+\frac{a_2}{(t+n)^2}+\dots$$
with large $t$. So as a first estimate I took $e_n=1+\frac{a_1}{t+n}$ so

$$L_M:=\log\prod_{n=0}^Me_n=\sum_{n=0}^M\log(1+\frac{a_1}{t+n})\approx\sum_{n=0}^M\frac{a_1}{t+n}.$$

It seems that $L_M$ grows like $\log M$ and the sum looks suspiciously close to the Taylor expansion of $\log(1-x)$. So can I bound somehow $L_M$ by $\log M$? If not, is there any other bound that can be applied and I cannot see?

Comment: $e_n$ is  infinite series ,right? Are there any conditions on $a_n$?

Comment: Yes, it is infinite and $a_n$ are bounded but I don't really know anything more. Actually for the specific case that I am looking, $a_1=2$.